# What moves can I do while driving to avoid being blocked and get a dunk?

Tags: nba2k11

More often than not, in a 1 on 1 fast break situation, my player (a guard) drives up to the basket, then ends up being blocked, pushed back by the opposing player, or has to do a layup or floater, missing more than 50% of the time.  What kind of moves can I do while driving at full speed at the basket to get a dunk or to avoid being blocked.  Also, what can I do to improve those layups since it doesn't seem to be about timing (i.e. holding down the shot key similar to shooting a 3 and getting a perfect release).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9342/how-do-i-finish-a-drive-in-nba-2k11/9949#9949) has several problems.

First of all, there is no release point for layups. Just hold down the shot stick.

Finishing around the basket is a skill that must be learned through repetition so you learn how to recognize spacing and know which move to select.

Only attempt a drive with players who are skilled at finishing around the basket. Guys like Rondo, Westbrook, Wall, Wade, etc. all have layup ratings of 90-99.

Never run straight at the defender and attempt a dunk/layup because 9 times out of 10 it will initiate a contact layup animation, and you'll miss/go cold.

Here's what you do. If there is a bit of space, once you hit the elbow area, press L2 + shot stick towards the basket for a Euro-step layup. Very high percentage move.

Or, even better, do a hop step, and then an up and under. That's triangle, then L2+shotstick away from basket, shotstick towards basket. Another money move.

And if all else fails and you end up in the paint with a defender right on you, pump fake a few times and draw the foul.

Master these 2 moves and you'll be able to score on fastbreaks at will. Getting around 1 defender is no problem and if you get good at these moves you can get around 2 defenders. And guys online will start quitting on you. These moves are high percentage because you can initiate their animations farther away from the basket, and once the animation starts, you'll usually Eurostep/hop right around the defender while avoiding contact, and end up directly underneath the basket for an open layup. Even if you get bumped and miss the shot, you'll almost always draw a foul. Test it out on Hall of Fame difficulty vs. the AI. You can literally take Kobe/melo/wade and do the Eurostep ALL GAME and probably end up shooting 30 freethrows.

Comment: I'm torn as to whether these are excellent suggestions or not. They certainly answer the question, which I suppose makes them excellent suggestions. However, they also exploit errors in the game design, which is bad sportsmanship. So if you like to be a hack then use the exploits mentioned because they do work, but you'll find most people don't want to play with you because you aren't scoring because you are good, you are simply exploiting flaws in the game which takes no skill, only knowledge of the flaws.

Answer (score 1):

First off when doing any inside move and finishing be sure to use the shoot button and not the shot stick.  You might find it hard to know when to release the shot stick for inside shots and especially on layups.

If you are open (no defense between you and the basket), as long as there is enough space for you to take your 2 steps and finish, you should be fine.  In terms of spacing it is better for you start your shot attempt further out, as opposed to attempting a layup directly under basket. When trying to pull off a dunk it depends on the player's rating, whether he has the ability to dunk and also if the player is heating up.  If a player is hot they tend to throw it down as opposed to laying it in.

If there is defense in front of you on the break you have a few options.

1. Pull back and set up the offense
2. Pull back and if the defense does not follow you, shoot a jumper (as long as your player can make it)
3. Try an iso move to get an opening and finish. You really have to time it well. Know when to use the turbo and time when to shoot.  There are some drills you can use in my player mode that can help you with this.

Hope this helps.